# Handsontable : How to choose which data to load?

Tags: json, handsontable

I have a json :

```
[{"name":"AA","age":"19","sex":"1","add":"yy","phone":"12345"},
 {"name":"BB","age":"20","sex":"0","add":"yy","phone":"43224"},
 {"name":"CC","age":"11","sex":"1","add":"yy","phone":"67863"},]
```

I want handsontable to load only **name, age**, but I don't know how to that :(

I think I should make a new object which only has name and age => load to handsontable. Can I do that?

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You *could* do it the way you initially suggested and modify your JSON object to only return those fields. Or, you could do it like this:

```
var data = [
 {"name":"AA","age":"19","sex":"1","add":"yy","phone":"12345"},
 {"name":"BB","age":"20","sex":"0","add":"yy","phone":"43224"},
 {"name":"CC","age":"11","sex":"1","add":"yy","phone":"67863"}
];

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  ...
  data: data,
  colHeaders: ['Name', 'Age'],
    columns: [
      {data: 'name'},
      {data: 'age'}
    ],
  ...
});
```

Using the `colHeaders` and `columns` options as in my example above gives you more flexibility with your data on the front end. :)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6t768pq/248/)